# How to initialize constants at runtime like in C++ initialisation lists?

Tags: c#, initialization, constants

Is there a way to initialize constant values in c# at runtime like with initialization lists in c++-ctors?

Specifically, I want to make sure that a specific value (the port used) is not changed after the main class was created. Maybe there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword:

> When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to
>   the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the
>   declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

Example (copied from the linked MSDN page):

```
class Age
{
    readonly int _year;
    Age(int year)
    {
        _year = year;
    }
    void ChangeYear()
    {
        //_year = 1967; // Compile error if uncommented.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works. Never noticed that there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static property without a setter:

```
private static int FPort = 1234;
public static int Port { get { return FPort; } }
```